# Securing a fiddle-like webapp for a compiler?

Tags: linux, web-services, security, fork, sandbox

I'm planning to build a web application that will let the user write his own code, compile and test it in-browser, like [phpFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/), or [Golang's tour](http://tour.golang.org/#1)

- I am aware that securing a server like this will be difficult.
- I know I could try to secure it by restricting access to the VM's standard lib (and I probably will), but I am aware that this isn't enough protection for all kinds of attacks, so it isn't a real protection at all.

Here's how I'm thinking about handling it:

- Master-slave configuration, with the slave servers only being accessible by the master one. The slaves will run a server that will spawn the compiler process in a chroot jail, as requested, and impose a timeout, so it will kill the application if it runs longer than a specified time.
- With the user-bound chroot, I can have a good control over what the user can access (specially since my target language doesn't have many dependencies), but I am sure that there are still rough edges left, for example:

  - How can I protect against the untrusted program running other independent processes? Is there a good way to deny a process to fork, or spawn any other processes?
  - What are other possible attack routes I may have overlooked?

I've made some searches to find good linux-based sandboxes, and while they seem quite nice, it seems to be a little bit of overkill to me, since my slave servers can be considered a sandbox by themselves, as I will dedicate them to the task of compiling/running the requested codes. That's why I'm asking this here and not in Serverfault, as it seems more programming-related than Server configuration-related.

Comment: [Codepad](http://codepad.org/about) has some good tips.

Comment: @Blender, thanks! It's a good idea to use ptrace(), though a code example would be great :)